# How to generate a random Unicode string including supplementary characters?

Tags: java, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I'm working on some code for generating random strings. The resulting string appears to contain invalid `char` combinations. Specifically, I find high surrogates which are not followed by a low surrogate.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Do I have to explicitly generate a random low surrogate to follow a high surrogate? I had assumed this wasn't needed, as I was using the `int` variants of the `Character` class.

Here's the test code, which on a recent run produced the following bad pairings:

```
Bad pairing: d928 - d863
Bad pairing: da02 - 7bb6
Bad pairing: dbbc - d85c
Bad pairing: dbc6 - d85c
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random r = new Random();
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  int count = 500;
  while (count > 0) {
    int codePoint = r.nextInt(Character.MAX_CODE_POINT + 1);

    if (!Character.isDefined(codePoint)
        || Character.getType(codePoint) == Character.PRIVATE_USE) {
      continue;
    }

    builder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
    count--;
  }

  String result = builder.toString();

  // Test the result
  char lastChar = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    char c = result.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(lastChar) && !Character.isLowSurrogate(c)) {
      System.out.println(String.format("Bad pairing: %s - %s",
          Integer.toHexString(lastChar), Integer.toHexString(c)));
    }
    lastChar = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Character.isDefined returns true for surrogates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to randomly generate high or low surrogates. If this results in a low surrogate, or a high surrogate not followed by a low surrogate, the resulting string is invalid. The solution is to simply exclude all surrogates:

```
if (!Character.isDefined(codePoint)
    || (codePoint <= Character.MAX_CHAR && Character.isSurrogate((char)codePoint))
    || Character.getType(codePoint) == Character.PRIVATE_USE) {
  continue;
}
```

Alternatively, it should work to only look at the type returned from `getType`:

```
int type = Character.getType(codePoint);
if (type == Character.PRIVATE_USE ||
    type == Character.SURROGATE ||
    type == Character.UNASSIGNED)
    continue;
```

(Technically, you could also allow randomly generated high surrogates and add another random low surrogate, but this would only create other random code points >= 0x10000 which might in turn be undefined or for private use.)

Comment: isSurrogate takes a character, not a codepoint.  I'm unsure if it's really safe to cast at this stage.

Comment: `Character.MAX_CHAR` seem to be a typo as it does not exist, do you mean `Character.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude *all* surrogate *orphans* (i.e. high-surrogate as well as low-surrogate ones).

FYI, next excerpt from [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) shows codepoint intervals for surrogates:

> ```
> D800;<Non Private Use High Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DB7F;<Non Private Use High Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DB80;<Private Use High Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DBFF;<Private Use High Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DC00;<Low Surrogate, First>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> DFFF;<Low Surrogate, Last>;Cs;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
> ```